# How to work with JSON native with flash css 5

Tags: json, actionscript-3, flash

I'm using the JSON class of as3corelib. It's handy, but I'm heaving some troubles, I saved a text codified and the same class can't decode it back - it's own code... :-@

Well, I'm thinking about move on to new native JSON, the plug in is 11.7, should work, however my compiler doesn't recognize a JSON class! I'm using Flash CSS5. It seams JSON native came only in some 5.5 version, is there a way of "implement" or "install" this class in my core?

My other alternative is get back to a codified text inside a xml I use to do...

Comment: Post some code. Preferably a minimal example of what you're trying.

Comment: The code is not relevant in this case since I wish to change it anyway. I'll try another library or back to my var with values encoded system that is primitive but works.

Answer (score 2):

[Native JSON parsing](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/JSON.html) is significantly higher performance than implementation found within as3corelib.

[image: JSON performance test]

Update the playerglobal.swc in Flash Pro to target a newer version of the Flash Player runtime.

1. You'll need to download the [playerglobal.swc](http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/updaters/11/playerglobal11_7.swc), which is available from [Adobe Flash Player Support Center](http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).
2. Place the playerglobal.swc in a FP11.7 folder in Flash Pro CS5 install path at /Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.7/playerglobal.swc

   Example: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.7
3. Create a publish target XML to add the Flash Player 11.7 option in Flash Pro's Publish settings dialog drop down.  These are found in /Common/Configuration/Players/

   Example: /Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/Players/FlashPlayer10_1.xml

   Copy and paste an existing Flash Player 10 XML as a template.

Comment: I just did, will test it. My doubt is about the "playerDefinitionPath" where there is "$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP10;" definition. Should be a "$(UserConfig)/Classes/FP11;"?

Comment: The error returned is: "Warning: 5004: The file '/Applications/Adobe Flash CS5/Common/Configuration/ActionScript 3.0/FP11.7/playerglobal.swc', which is required for typechecking ActionScript 3.0, could not be found. You may need to reinstall Flash.". Since I did put the file there, I guess is permissions problems. There was another strange errors like lost base class, so there is more hack to do. I think I'll let this work for the professionals, but thanks for try!

Comment: Follow any number of tutorials to overlay a new Flash runtime to Flash Pro, such as [Adding Flash Player 11 support to Flash Pro CS5 and CS5.5](http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html).